# How do I get or make large glitter paper sheets for origami stars?

Tags: material-selection, paper, technique-selection, origami, props

I'm trying to make a ton of origami stars (like how I (and many others) used to in middle school) for a future music/live performance, but I want them to be the most glitzed-out 2000's glitter puke imaginable, while still being thin and foldable enough to make them by hand.

Like so bright and shiny that it'll be noticeable in dive bar lighting. I **don't** want to use anything that would risk the glitter coming off. I'm thinking almost holographic of glittery sticker paper but no adhesive and very large sheets.

If the large uncut sheets don't exist premade, how would I go about making it without risking getting glitter everywhere?

Picture for clarity on what I'd be folding them into.
I would like some of them to be larger, though, so I can attach a tab for people to unfold them, and a thing with maybe my artist name or a QR code to a single (a "single" song. you can make any website link into a QR code now) will be inside, I'm not sure yet.

I want the regular ones to be about a half inch tall maybe a bit taller with a few bigger 1-2" ones with stuff inside.

Does anyone know where I could get large sheets of glittery/holographic paper that's easily bendable? I'm looking for foldable holographic or glittery sheets/paper at least 8.5" x 11" but would prefer something like a roll almost like wallpaper or gift wrap but I'm having a hard time finding any of those as bright or non-holiday specific as I need.

The image is just from googling "paper stars":

[image: Photo of different colored origami stars]

Comment: What size? There's nothing for scale in the image

Comment: Hard to bend holographic texture papers and other thicker paper stock can be made easier to bend by scoring them first (scoring is a light cut that does not go all the way through the paper.)

Answer (score 6):

Actual glitter paper relies on bonding glitter to paper (or card) and it always sheds, whether bought or home made.  You may be able to spray coat it and reduce the shedding, but you won't stop it completely.

Instead you might look at (textured) metallic foil card, or holographic card.  Both can go quite thin, and while they're not the exact effect you're going for, in dive bar lighting during the performance, the larger reflections may actually be better, though less good for the ones being handled.

Otherwise, you could fold, cover with spray adhesive, then apply glitter (probably quite a coarse glitter).  Brush over with a soft brush to remove loose bits then apply a glossy spray sealer (or lacquer, or varnish, depending on what's available) to stick it down better.   This approach would probably result in the most robust final product with real glitter, at the expense of considerably more effort.

Anything reflective needs light to reflect, and directional lighting, like spotlights, works far better than anything more diffuse, as you get the glinting effect.

Comment: i mean glitter like how glitter or holographic stickers are glitter. im trying to avoid the actual material because i dont think anyone going to the performance will want to deal with picking it out of their hair 4 months later. holographic card isnt a bad idea i just cant seem to find thin kinds.

Comment: An idea of size would be good in that case  (sheet size, not star size, as only you know what design you're folding).  I can easily find A4 120gsm, but you've given no idea if that would be big enough.  Holographic gift wrap is cheap enough to have a go with, if you can find some that's actual paper that takes a crease, rather than plastic, but as you said "glitter", I was looking more for glitter solutions than different sheet materials

Comment: Looks like there are adhesive holographic papers out there (googled "holo paper"). So you could fold your stars out of plain paper then cut out and add glittery paper as decals later.